# How to add missing dimensions to all images to avoid cls?

Tags: images

My sites have lots of external images without dimensions, and that's causing layout shift.
I need a code which automatically add missing width and height to all images.
I tried 1 plugin [Specify Missing Image Dimensions](https://wordpress.org/plugins/specify-missing-image-dimensions) but site become too slow after activating this plugin.
Thanks

Comment: I don't know that plugin, but I can imagine why it would be slow to start with: it's going to have to fetch each image and read the size the first time. Hopefully it would then cache the size by remote image URL somewhere, provided the remote images don't change. I don't think there's a good way to do that otherwise.

Comment: But if you're worried about layout shift, why not just add in the heights and widths on your site for the sizes you want the images to be?

Comment: Actually i have auto blogging site which import content from other sites. So i have no control on image attributes.

Comment: You do have control of the import process though, so you can add them then?